# Группировка (кластеризация) данных на пересечении атрибутов

Tags: node.js, статистика, обработка, кластеризация

Здравствуйте!
Есть данные формата

```
тест1 = ["яблоко", "тыква", "груша"], 
тест2 = ["тыква", "апельсин", "ананас", "грейпфрут"]
тест3 = ["мандарин", "лимон", "тыква", "яблоко"]
тест4 = ["тыква", "апельсин", "персик", "грейпфрут"]
```

Нужно сгруппировать их по максимальной похожести, например, тест1 похож на тест3 на пересечении "яблока" и "тыквы", значит их степень похожести - 2. Тест2 похож на тест4 в степени похожести 3, нужно чтобы было максимально много совпадений в каждой группе. Ограничений по количеству элементов в группе нет. Натыкался на 
индекс Жаккара, но производительно реализовать группировку с помощью него - не вышло (на маленьких выборках работает неплохо, более тысячи уже неработоспособно)

Решение пишу под node.js, но самое главное - направьте куда копать, пожалуйста. Может есть какие то готовые решения, а я тут мучаюсь.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: я думаю elasticsearch то что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Вообще, я уже привел к нужному виду данные, все таки оптимизировал работу с jaccard index. Посмотрел elasticsearch, инструмент кажется годным, но сложным. Не могли бы вы направить дополнительно куда смотреть чтобы делать подобные группировки? Хочу сравнить результат es с своим решением.

Comment: вот есть легенький пример - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806391/elasticsearch-filtering-aggregations-from-array-field
Там копать не перекопать :) 
Могу поделиться личным опытом, 2 млн документов, агрегация по 4 полям + суммирование уникальных полей и построение гистограммы данных у меня занимает 60-100 миллисекунд.